# WebKitFormBoundary header on file ulpoad

Tags: ajax, node.js, api, file-upload

To avoid sharing a third-service api token, I want to upload my files trough my node server.

To do this, I've my webpage sending my files in ajax to my node server which is sending them to the 3rd party api.

so :

```
client > ajax > node > api
```

My file succeed to arrive on the third party service but with WebKitFormBoundary header and footer.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryBvPXh46XrNOYDFJn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Screen Shot 2014-11-20 at 15.01.45.png"
Content-Type: image/png

<< file bytes >>
------WebKitFormBoundaryBvPXh46XrNOYDFJn--
```

Ajax code :

```
$.uploadFiles = function(file){

        var data = new FormData();

        data.append('file', file, file.name);

        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({
            //url: 'https://slack.com/api/files.upload?token=xoxp-2964595734-2964595740-3128685143-b1796a&channels='+settings.joinedChannel+'&pretty=1',
            url: '/app/fileUpload?token='+settings.token+'&channel='+settings.joinedChannel,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false, // Don't process the files
            contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
                {
                    // Success so call function to process the form
                    //submitForm(event, data);
                    console.log(data);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle errors here
                    console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                // Handle errors here
                console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
                // STOP LOADING SPINNER
            }
        });

    };
```

Node code

```
app.post('/app/fileUpload', isAuthorized, function(req, res, next) {

    var token            = req.param('token');
    var channel          = req.param('channel');
    var req              = req;

    models.app.find({ where: { token: token, active: true } }).success(function(application) {
        slack.uploadFile(application.slack_api_token,channel,req);
        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: "Uploading" });
    });

});

[....]

uploadFile: function uploadFile(applicationToken,channel,file) {

    var formData = {
        // Pass a simple key-value pair
        token: applicationToken,

        // Pass a simple key-value pair
        channels: channel,

        // Pass data via Streams
        file: file

    };

    request.post('https://slack.com/api/files.upload?pretty=1', { formData: formData }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200 && typeof body.ok !== "undefined" && body.ok == true) {
            console.log("OK");
            //console.log(body);
        } else {
            console.log("Not OK");
            //console.log(response);
        }
    });

},
```

FIXED : with [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) and this code to manage the file stream :

```
file: {
    value:  fs.createReadStream(stream.file.path),
        options: {
            filename: stream.file.name,
            contentType: stream.file.type
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should avoid responding to the request until all of the request data is read, otherwise you may lose data because sending the response terminates the connection/request.

Comment: You were right, I've fixed this with [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) to parse and this code to manage the stream : `file: {
       value:  fs.createReadStream(stream.file.path),
       options: {
         filename: stream.file.name,
         contentType: stream.file.type
       }
     }` Thanks for your idea ;)